# Is this the correct way to use the word "candidacy" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, mathematics

In a math article I want to say that if a subset A of a set X has a certain property N then X is a candidate for being a "stable bundle" (what ever that means).

**Question :** Is this the correct way to write it? -

> If property N happens for the subset A then this will ensure the candidacy of X to be a stable bundle

or this ?

> If property N is true for the subset A then this will ensure the candidacy of X to be a stable bundle

Thank you.

Comment: This might be a better fit on mathematics.se

Comment: But this is about the use of an English word. Shouldn't it be here?

Comment: Depends, if this is a set phrase in math papers you might get better answers over there. I don't know. That's why I wrote *might* and not will. I also didn't vote to close. I'm just saying it might be worth your time to have a look over there.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. But if it is not a set phrase then is the usage correct?

Comment: Grammatically, sure they are correct. Although I don't know why you don't use the way you used in your introduction. I would prefer that over your other two options.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the advice. I think I'll use the sentence I used in the introduction.

Comment: 'Ensure the candidacy of X being Y'? Wouldn't everybody write 'means that it is possible that X is Y'? And what does one gain from saying 'If P is true, then Q is also possibly true'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't like *ensuring* that something is a *candidate*.  We could ensure that something is definitely a whatever (e.g. member of some set or class).

Saying that something is a candidate is a pretty weak statement, so "ensure" sounds out of place in that context.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Ensuring something is a candidate is a strange sentence. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is slightly better. The phrase "a property happens" in the first quote is awkward. But the phrase "ensure the candidacy" is awkward too.

You can make it even better by saying it more simply.  Try this:

> If property N is true for the subset A, then X is certainly a candidate to be a stable bundle

Or

> If property N is true for the subset A, then X is a candidate to be a stable bundle

Or

> If property N is true for the subset A, then X may be a stable bundle.